# Compositions of relations functions and inverse

Tags: functions

$Let$ $N = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $Let$ $k : N → N, g : N → N$ and $m : N → N$

$k = \{(1, 3),(2, 1),(3, 4),(4, 2)\}$

$g = \{(1, 2),(2, 4),(3, 4),(4, 3)\}$

$m = \{(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2)\}$

my reasons for injectivity,surjectivity, and bijections or none are as follows (correct me if they are wrong or there are more reasons)

for $k$:

Injectivity-Yes as all x's in the domain mao to a unique value in the co-domain

Surjectivity-Yes- All the values in the co-domain have at least one value mapping from the domain

Bijection-Yes as it is injective and surjective

for $g$:
Injectivity-No as 2 and 3 in the domain map to one value in the co-domain,4 and 2!=3

Surjective-No as 1 in the co-domain is not mapped from the domain

Bijectivity-No as it is not surjective and injective

therefore none

for $m$:

Injectivity-No as $m(1),m(2),m(3),m(4)=2$ in the co-domain, in other words, all the values in the domain map to one single value in the co domain therefore there is no uniqueness

Surjectivity: No-as only 2 is mapped from the domain

Bijective-No

Therefore None

The questions are
work out

1. $k\circ k$, $k\circ g$ , $g\circ k$
2. $(k\circ m)\circ g$
3. Calcuate the inverse of $k,g,m$ if there are any?

**My attempt**

1)$k\circ k = \{(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)\}$
b)$k\circ g = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(4,4)\}
c)$g\circ k ={(1,4),(2,2),(3,3),4,4)}

2. $(k\circ m)\circ g$=$\{(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)\}$
3. only $k$ is invertible as it is injective
   $k^-1$ = $\{3,1),(1,2),(4,3),(2,4)\}$

Any kind of help or suggestions will be much appreciated in both on my attempt or for my reasonings on injectivity, surjectivity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> 3. only k is invertible as it is injective k−1 = {3,1),(1,2),(4,3),(2,4)}

Everything seems correct both the calculation and the reasonings. In this part, I believe the reason should be that only k is invertible as it is the only **bijective function**
For an inverse function to exist, the function  must be both injective and surjective [Hence bijective]

According to Wikipedia

> For a function f: X → Y to have an inverse, it must have the property that for every y in Y, there is exactly one x in X such that f(x) = y. This property ensures that a function g: Y → X exists with the necessary relationship with f.